# How to retrieve the value of DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc In Windows xp?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, driver, device-driver

I can call SetupDiGetDeviceProperty to retrieve the value of DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc according to msdn document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542369(v=vs.85).aspx . 
But this value only available in Windows 7 and later versions of Windows. How to retrieve the value of DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc In Windows xp?
The App is a win32 service,not a device driver.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent in Windows 2000 and XP is [SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).